# Vector get() method returns last element on every index

Tags: java

I am trying to reference the **profile_channels** Vector by using the get() method to return the value at that index. Although it returns the last value at every index of the Vector. The code prints each element of the Vector as it is created and they all print correctly and in order, but the issue is only when using the get() method. This code is for a SAX XML Parser.

```
try {

        handler = new DefaultHandler(){
            int channel_amt = 0;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localname, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                if(name == "fixture"){
                    profileID++;
                    profile_name = attributes.getValue(0);
                    profile_mode = attributes.getValue(1);
                    profile_channels.clear();
                } else {

                    if(name == "channel"){

                        profile_channel.clear();
                        profile_channel.addElement(attributes.getValue(0));
                        profile_channel.addElement(attributes.getValue(1));
            //          profile_channel.addElement(Boolean.parseBoolean(attributes.getValue(2)));

                        channel_amt++;
                        if(Arrays.asList(channels).indexOf(attributes.getValue(1)) != -1){
                            profile_channel_function[Arrays.asList(channels).indexOf(attributes.getValue(1))] = channel_amt;
                        }

                    } else {
                        profile_channel.addElement(new Range(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(0)), Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(1)), attributes.getValue(2)));
                    }

                } 

            }       
            public void endElement(String uri, String localname, String name) throws SAXException {

                if(name == "fixture"){
                    profile[profileID] = new Profile(profile_name, profile_mode, profile_channels, profile_built_in_dimmer, profile_channel_function);
                    System.out.println(profile_channels.get(2));
                } else if(name == "channel"){
                    System.out.println(profile_channel);
                    profile_channels.add(profile_channel);
                }

            }
        };
        loadProfile("test.xml");
```

Any ideas? The print statements at the bottom are where I am printing elements of the Vector.

Comment: use equals to compare Strings, not ==

Comment: Why are you using `Vector`, rather than `List` ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you expect the code to do. I see one Vector.get() call in this code, and its parameter is a constant value of 2. Given that you always use the same index, I don't understand why you're saying "it returns the last value at every index of the Vector.".

Answer (score 0):

It does not return the last element of the Vector, but it always returns the exact **same** element for any *get()* call.

That's because it is what you do: you're re-using one instance of an object, changing its state and add it multiple times to the Vector.

You need to create a new profile_channel instance every time a "channel" element occurs.